# Cocoa NSButton with underlined title

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsbutton

I'm trying to create a NSButton with an underlined title.

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: NSButton!
let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single]
let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Button Title", attributes: underlineAttribute)
myButton.attributedTitle = underlineAttributedString
```

But I get the error:

```
<NSATSTypesetter: 0x600003719500>: Exception -[__SwiftValue _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000ca4060 raised during typesetting layout manager <NSLayoutManager: 0x100e1a140>
    1 containers, text backing has 5 characters
    selected character range {0, 0} affinity: upstream granularity: character
    marked character range {0, 0}
    Currently holding 5 glyphs.
    Glyph tree contents:  5 characters, 5 glyphs, 1 nodes, 64 node bytes, 256 storage bytes, 320 total bytes, 64.00 bytes per character, 64.00 bytes per glyph
    Layout tree contents:  5 characters, 5 glyphs, 0 laid glyphs, 0 laid line fragments, 1 nodes, 64 node bytes, 0 storage bytes, 64 total bytes, 12.80 bytes per character, 12.80 bytes per glyph, 0.00 laid glyphs per laid line fragment, 0.00 bytes per laid line fragment
, glyph range {0 5}. Ignoring...
```

Is it possible to create an underlined title in general?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357238/underline-button-text-in-swift. <br> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31359103/9048325

Comment: Ha! It looks like setting NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle to NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue did the trick... Weird... but thanks for the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you figured it out, but for documentation purposes: <s>`NSUnderlineStyle.single`</s> -> `NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue`

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: NSButton!

let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Button Title", attributes: underlineAttribute)
myButton.attributedTitle = underlineAttributedString
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! One year later and happy to find your answer.