How to underline title with UIButton.Configuration?
This is my convenience init for UIButton:
convenience init(underlinedTitle: String, font: UIFont, color: UIColor) {
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    configuration.title = underlinedTitle
    configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
        var outgoing = incoming
        outgoing.font = font
        outgoing.foregroundColor = color
        outgoing.underlineStyle = .single
        outgoing.underlineColor = color
        return outgoing
    }
    self.init(configuration: configuration)
}

and the effect is following:

Why is it not underlined?

You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76699208/6257435

No, it doesnt work...‍♂️

Hmm... can't find this documented anywhere, but appears to be correct.
To add underline style:
outgoing.underlineStyle = [.single]

To remove underline style:
outgoing.underlineStyle = []


try use way from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41166179/11335258
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!

var attrs = [
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0),
NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),
NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : 1]

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"")

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let buttonTitleStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"My Button", attributes:attrs)
  attributedString.appendAttributedString(buttonTitleStr)
  yourButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: .Normal)
}

